# No passwords on Sourcecode

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to improve my webpage security by not showing passwords DIRECTLY on the source code.

Is there a way to read them from a text file?

Here's my login source code:

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function Login(){
var done=0;
var username=document.login.username.value;
username=username.toLowerCase();
var password=document.login.password.value;
password=password.toLowerCase();
if (username=="admin" && password=="admin") { window.location="u.php?username=admin"
done=1; }
if (username=="super" && password=="super") { window.location="u.php?username=super"
done=1; }
if (username=="normal" && password=="normal") {window.location="u.php?username=normal"
done=1; }
if (done==0) { alert("Contrasena incorrecta!"); }
}
// End -->
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<center>
<form name=login method="post" action="QrTwPOKuser=admin.php">
<table width=225 border=1 cellpadding=3>
<tr><td colspan=2><center><font size="+2"><b>Acceso a Usuarios</b></font></center
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Usuario :</td><td><input type=text name=username></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type=password name=password></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type=button value="Login!" onClick="Login()">   </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
<p><center>
<font face="arial, helvetica" size="-2">Sistema de cobro Sanisidro<br>
by <a href="http://www.4suredesign.com">Borbolla</a></font>
</center><p>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
window.history.forward();
function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

Comment: Soooo.... your only protection is this Javascript? Let me demonstrate how I will hack your system... I'll just type `u.php?username=admin` into my address bar and hit enter. Oooops, login system hacked!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because what is this I don't even. This is so far removed from an actually secure login system, the part the question is about is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I'm new at web programing, any ideas on improving this are welcome :)

Comment: This is actually horrifying.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do any type of security in the browser as whatever the browser sees is essentially in the open and anyone can also see. Security should be done server side.

Comment: You need an actual login system written on the server in a server side language. You cannot have a login system exclusively in client-side Javascript. Start from scratch by following an appropriate tutorial.

Comment: You're using PHP, pass the username and password to the php script, decide if they are valid or not, then serve the protected page or a page that says the password/username combo is invalid. It's Web-101 stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you read your password from a text file view source will enable anyone to see your password. DO NOT do login validation in javascript.

Comment: So I should do it with PHP and MySQL?

Comment: if you are going with database, make sure you have encryption in place and multiple validation. and be wary of sql injection

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. Hash them, with a salt.